# Looking for sequelize.js REST API generator with associations support

Tags: node.js, rest, sequelize.js

Is there any node.js module which would provide full REST api sequelize?

Which must follow associations, so for example if I have tables testsuites (hasMany testcases) and testcases, than the api will allow me to do: get /api/testsuite/1/testcases and it will do all the magic for me?

I checked sequelize-restful, but does not seems to work this way :(

Comment: Could you post the code for the Models in question? I am wondering how you are defining the relationship between the two models.

Comment: Check if this can help https://github.com/arorarahul/node-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

See below libraries can help you in generating REST API with sequelize

1.https://github.com/dchester/epilogue
2.https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-restful

Example: https://github.com/pjanaya/nodejs-express4-sequelize-restful